# How to keep running RecognizerIntent and get the speech to text string from the mic input

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, speech-to-text, voice

```
        string rec = global::Android.Content.PM.PackageManager.FeatureMicrophone;
        if (rec == "android.hardware.microphone")
        {
            var voiceIntent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ActionRecognizeSpeech);
            voiceIntent.PutExtra(RecognizerIntent.ExtraLanguageModel, RecognizerIntent.LanguageModelFreeForm);
            voiceIntent.PutExtra(RecognizerIntent.ExtraSpeechInputCompleteSilenceLengthMillis, 1500);
            voiceIntent.PutExtra(RecognizerIntent.ExtraSpeechInputPossiblyCompleteSilenceLengthMillis, 1500);
            voiceIntent.PutExtra(RecognizerIntent.ExtraSpeechInputMinimumLengthMillis, 15000);
            voiceIntent.PutExtra(RecognizerIntent.ExtraMaxResults, 1);
            voiceIntent.PutExtra(RecognizerIntent.ExtraLanguage, Java.Util.Locale.Default);
            _activity.StartActivityForResult(voiceIntent, 10);
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception("No mic found");
        }
```

I'm passing the current activity using "Plugin.CurrentActivity" plugin.What I want to do is continuously run the listener without prompting google speech popup.Listener should not stop until it stop by a button.

Comment: The recognition will continue indefinitely if you don't speak or make any detectable sound.I don't think there needs to be a button to stop manually.

Comment: it's continuously runing but how to stop the prompt window?

Comment: Maybe you could try to call `FinishActivity(request_code);` in your case.